# Error in closing IE Window on Citrix Server with c#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I want to close IE Windows when the URL contains a string like: cobra

I have this code and it works on my local machine:

```
foreach (InternetExplorer explorer in new ShellWindowsClass()) {

    String url = explorer.LocationURL;

    if (url.Contains("cobra")) {
        explorer.Quit();
    }
}
```

The IE and this code are now on y Citrix System and when this code is used i got the Exception:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
foreach (InternetExplorer ie in new ShellWindows()) {
            //...
        }
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer, showing what it does and how it solves the problem. This will help others who see your answer in the future

Comment: I changed it to your answer but it doesen't close the window or tab.

Comment: The new ShellWindowsClass() or new ShellWindows() throws the exception

Answer (score 0):

I searched and found that `new SHDocVw.ShellWindows()` is not going to work in Citrix environment. As given on this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/abd13aaa-df8a-44a9-b7c0-783e9cb07364/shdocvwshellwindows-sw-new-shellwindows?forum=csharpgeneral)

> It appears that ShellWindows class (used to enumerate InternetExplorer
>   windows) is hosted by explorer.exe process.
>
> Thus since Citrix in seamless mode does not run explorer.exe

So you can use other ways like

> FindWindowEx method of user32.dll

See the above link for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas.

The First Code is the same that i'm using. At the moment when new ShellWindows()  i got the Exception in the Citrix Enviroment (see first text)

The second Code from you kills the complete IE, i want only to close the tab with the url containing a string.

Comment: No the first code is not exactly same, I have used ShellWindows instead of ShellWindowsClass and there is one extra check for FullName. Have you tried this code?

Comment: The new ShellWindowsClass() or new ShellWindows() throws the exception